# Set layout margin for element in relativeLayout by code

Tags: android, margin, android-relativelayout

I have codes of a `RelativeLayout` activity.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"          
    android:background="#686868"  
>
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title_header"  
        android:text="Header of page"  
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is code of Activity:-

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        int valCheck;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
                if(valCheck==0)
                {
                    //here set title again for backbutton is "backPreviousPage" and set  
                    //position again of title_header is right of backButton with 
                    //margin=5dip(not set position is centerInParent as code

                }


    }

}
```

I don't know the way to get element and set margin in relativeLayout by code..Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(80, 0, 0, 0); //left, top, right, bottom
params.height = 60; //set height dynamically
params.width = 200; // set width dynamically
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: headView and head_params is where?

Answer (score 0):

To access UI Elements within Android code, you use the `findViewById` method. For example:

```
Button btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
```

Once you have access to all of the elements you need, you can use the setter functions provided in the API to change the layout as need-be. Since most (if not all) UI elements are a child class of the View class, the methods you will need will most likely be defined there. Here is a good reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

All View objects inherit the `setLayoutParams` method. So you can apply the method suggested by Gunaseelan to your Button and your TextView as well.

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params  = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 1001);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 1000);
```

Here id 1001  and 1000 is my `EditText` `id` which also dynamic added to Relative

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"          
    android:background="#686868"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  
>
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
/>
<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title_header"  
    android:text="Header of page"  
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in java code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int valCheck;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
            if(valCheck==0)
            {
                //here set title again for backbutton is "backPreviousPage" and set  
                //position again of title_header is right of backButton with 
                //margin=5dip(not set position is centerInParent as code
                btn.setText("backPreviousPage");
            }
    }
}
```